# Time Complexity of three nested for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

There are three nested for loops, and I can find complexity if the loop increment by 1 but if the loop increment like this i+=c, I got confused?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=c)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
             for (int k=0; k < m; k++)
                 result[i,j]= x[j]-y[k]
```

The complexity of the third for loop is m but for the first for loop I think is n/c and for the second for loop is n ==> multiply ranges together: n/c * n * m = n^2/c * m ==> the worst case is O(n^2). is this correct?
How to find the total number of iterations using the sum form?

Comment: What is m? Is it the length of the array?

Comment: Yes, m and n is the length of two different arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity depends on two parameters in your case: `m` and `n` as the middle loop can be expressed as a function of the first.

If you consider the total number of iterations they are of the order of:

```
1/2 * m * n * (n-1) = O(mn^2)
```

The left part assumes `c=1`. However, given `c` as a constant the overall time complexity would not change.

If c is not given as a constant the resulting time complexity would be `O(mn^2)/c`

Comment: I guess you should divide that by `c` due to `i += c`

Comment: Thanks for your help. My confusion was with the c part and I saw many examples here if i+=2, the complexity will be n/2. The c will have different values each time the program run.

Comment: but if n^2 is dominant, should I include it alone on big O notation or should include all variables O(mn^2/c)?!

Comment: Depends if you have additional info on `m` and you can characterize it. For instance, if `m=O(n^2)` and `c=O(1)` then it becomes `O(n^4)`, but if you don't have any info on it, then you should leave, as the time complexity also depends on it by being part of the input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.